# how to find length of an object

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am struggling to find the length of a message object. The given task is as follow: The exercise template comes with a pre-defined Message class that can be used to create objects representing messages. Each message has a sender and some content.

Implement the MessagingService class. The class must have a parameterless constructor and contain a list of Message objects. After that, add the following two methods to the class:

public void add(Message message) - adds a message passed as a parameter to the messaging service as long as the message content is at most 280 characters long.
public ArrayList getMessages() - returns the messages added to the messaging service.
Tip! You can find out the length of the string using the length() method associated with the string.

What I have done is:

> import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MessagingService {
    ArrayList messages;

```
public MessagingService(){
    this.messages = new ArrayList();
}
public void add(Message message){
    if(message.length() <= 280){
        messages.add(message);
    }

}

public ArrayList<Message> getMessages(){
    ArrayList<Message> mess = new ArrayList();
    for(Message m:messages){
        mess.add(m);
    }
    return mess;
}
```

}

import java.util.Objects;

public class Message {

```
private String sender;
private String content;

public Message(String sender, String content) {
    this.sender = sender;
    this.content = content;
}

public String getSender() {
    return sender;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public String toString() {
    return this.sender + ": " + this.content;
}
public int length(){
    return this.length();
}

// created using the "insert code" feature of NetBeans
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Message other = (Message) obj;
    if (!Objects.equals(this.sender, other.sender)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.content, other.content)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Blockquote

Comment: what do you mean by length of message object ?Is it the length of the content ?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your Message class, this is nonsense. It will throw stackoverflow exception:

```
public int length(){
    return this.length();
}
```

What you probably need here is:

```
 public int length(){
        return content.length();
    }
```